# How to make a function with random numbers

Tags: python, function, random, iteration

Hi  I am trying to create a function that will select 5 random numbers which will equal a total amount already given and put the 5 numbers in a list.  When I pass a number through the function I get an error.
I cant seem to get what Im doing wrong.

```
def num_lottery(total_num):
    the_set =[]
    n1 = random.randint(1, total_num)
    n2 = random.randint(1, total_num - n1)
    n4 = random.randint(1, total_num - (n1 + n2 + n3))
    n5 = total_num - (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4)
    the_set.append(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5)
    return the_set
```

It works when I pass through the total_num = 50000, but not when total_num = 5000.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Seems like you missed `n3` initialization.

Comment: This code works for me, after adding the n3 initialization.

Comment: `I get an error.` - what does that mean? `but not when total_num = 5000` - what do you expect as a result?

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't now anything about python coding, but take a look at the variable n3 in your code:

```
def num_lottery(total_num):
    the_set =[]
    n1 = random.randint(1, total_num)
    n2 = random.randint(1, total_num - n1)
    n4 = random.randint(1, total_num - (n1 + n2 + **n3**))
    n5 = total_num - (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4)
    the_set.append(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5)
    return the_set
```

It isn't defined anywhere.
I think you meant:

```
def num_lottery(total_num):
    the_set =[]
    n1 = random.randint(1, total_num)
    n2 = random.randint(1, total_num - n1)
    **n3 = random.randint(1, total_num - (n1+n2)**
    n4 = random.randint(1, total_num - (n1 + n2 + **n3**))
    n5 = total_num - (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4)
    the_set.append(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5)
    return the_set
```

I hope that does the trick.

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)